# how do I make a tiled UV island without this white line?(node Fraction)

Tags: node-editor, image

I started learning how to create shaders. I saw an interesting technique on the network, but I did not understand how to remove this white line and why it appears in it. I would be very grateful for a way to remove it to get a good tiling.[image]

I'm trying to make a tile on two different UV islands and use one texture ,atlas.
[image]

Comment: Can you explain the reason for the Fraction? Doesn't the texture appear the same (but without the lines) if you omit it and simply use object texture coordinates?

Comment: I'm trying to do tiling on two different UV Islands. Added a picture to the post.